# Changing Calendar object to a string

Tags: java, date, object, calendar

I`m having an issue with changing the calendar to a string. When I run the program, the calendar is not being changed to a date. This is my code:

```
switch(selection){
    case 1:
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.getTime().toString();
        LifeTimeMembers lifetime = new LifeTimeMembers();
        lifetime.setName(name);
        lifetime.setSurname(surname);
        lifetime.setAddress(address);
        lifetime.setJoinDate(cal);
        members.add(lifetime);
        break;
    case 2:
        cal.add(Calendar.YEAR, 1);
        YearlyMembers yearly = new YearlyMembers(name, surname, address, cal);
        members.add(yearly);
        break;
}
System.out.println("Member added");
```

Can someone help me please?

Comment: Couldn't understand your question.

Comment: What do you want to achive with the line cal.getTime().toString();

Comment: AND - What is the type of setJoinDate? Date?

Comment: check bizmark answer below. It's recommended to use Joda Time to deal with dates in Java: http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/

Comment: I don't think JODA is needed for something as simple as this.  Why add another dependency?

Answer (score 2):

first format the coming date.

```
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MMM-dd");
Date d=dateFormat.format(cal);
```

parse that date to string

```
String dateAsStr = dateFormat.format(d);
```

Answer (score 1):

`cal.getTime().toString();` is returning a value, but you are not doing anything with it.

Instead do something like

`String timeAsString = cal.getTime().toString();` and then use `timeAsString` however you like in your program.

You can see the default format for [Date.toString()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#toString%28%29). If you want to format it, then check the documentation for the [DateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) class.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you want, but perhaps this will do it:

```
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MMM-dd");
dateFormat.setLenient(false);
Date d = cal.getTime();
String dateAsStr = dateFormat.format(d);
```

Comment: This is what I am getting with my code:  Join Date: java.util.GregorianCalendar[time=1363959072596,areFieldsSet=true,areAllFieldsSet=true,lenient=true,zone=sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo[id="Europe/Berlin",offset=3600000,dstSavings=3600000,useDaylight=true,transitions=143,lastRule=java.util.SimpleTimeZone[id=Europe/Berlin,offset=3600000,dstSavings=3600000,useDaylight=true,startYear=0,startMode=2,startMonth=2,startDay=-1,startDayOfWeek=1,startTime=3600000,start TimeMode=2,endMode=2,endMonth=9,endDay=-1,endDayOfWeek=1,endTime=3600000,endTimeMode=2]],firstDayOfWeek=2,minimalDaysInFirstWeek=4,ERA=1...

Comment: You don't need that stuff.  Make the join date a java.util.Date - that's all you need.  Why all this fuss?